# How to use ZoneOffset, ZoneId with LocalDateTime properly in Java 8?

Tags: java, java-time

The objective here is to convert LocalDateTime to epoch second back and forth.

Suppose I have a LocalDateTime defined as:

```
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
```

I want to convert it to epoch second in time Asia/Kolkata time zone which I can do like:

```
long epochSecondNow = now.atZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata")).toEpochSecond();
```

Now, I want to generate the 'now' again from epochSecondNow:

LocalDateTime class has a method '
`ofEpochSecond(long epochSecond,long nanoOfSecond, ZoneOffset zoneOffset)`' which takes epoch second, nano of second and ZoneOffset as arguments.

I am not able to create ZoneOffset using "Asia/Kolkata". How should I make the ZoneOffset object for my zone in order to make use of 'ofEpochSecond' method. 
Is there any other way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Try use with Instant.ofEpochSecond

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond(epochSecondNow);
ZonedDateTime atZone = instant.atZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata"));
LocalDateTime localDateTime = atZone.toLocalDateTime();
```

If you want to use with system time zone, can do with ZoneId.systemDefault()

Comment: Thanks, that's better. Don't want to use system default as I need to fix the time zone at application layer itself as system default may differ on remote servers.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I just did this in following way, by obtaining the ZoneOffset by passing the offset value as String:

```
LocalDateTime nowFromEpochSecond = LocalDateTime.ofEpochSecond(epochSecondNow,0,ZoneOffset.of("+05:30"));
```

I hope there is a cleaner way to do it, instead of hard coding offset and zone id.